# At the end of Thor: Ragnarok why don't the Asgardians turn and head for the Bifrost as per their original plan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

At the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*, the Asgardians are heading for the Bifrost when they are intercepted by Hela's soldiers and Fenris.

After they are all destroyed and only Hela herself remained, the Asgardians still jumped onto Loki's ship instead of heading to the Bifrost which would have teleported them instantly to Earth instead of the long journey via spaceship.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They had to use the ship initially because Valkyrie blocked the bridge with the party ship she, Thor and Banner escaped from Sakaar in.

[image: Valkyrie blocking the Bifrost bridge]

By the time they are airborne and escaping, Surtur has already started Ragnarok, which is in the process of destroying Asgard and therefore the Observatory. As such, there was no time to get into the Observatory and escape through the Bifrost.

It's also worth noting that a bunch of Asgardians had already entered the ship whilst they were surrounded and so it would take even more time to unload them and move them onto the Observatory again. Speed is of the essence here.

Comment: I think the ship actually crashes on the Asgard side, rather than the Bifrost side — although the 8-bit map sequence is a bit confusing, as it pans over to Asgard in what is apparently the direction of the Bifrost.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was trying to work it out but from [this clip](http://freegifmaker.me/img/res/1/5/5/5/4/1/15554196981345648.gif?1555419702) it looks like it is Observatory side. In the background you can't see any of Asgard either but just "emptiness".

Comment: Yeah, the ship is clearly travelling toward the Bifrost observatory when it crashes. But I think it still lands with the Asgardians between it and the observatory. It's on the Asgard side. It's just a really long bridge.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I always assumed it was Observatory side, you don't see the ship in the background of either angle though so I don't know.

Comment: There's a brief shot around 1:46, where Hela shows Thor the bridge battle. You can see what looks like jet trail from the ship as it's crashing, which I think suggests it's on the Asgard side.

Comment: I think this is correct. Hela has Asgard behind her. Loki is facing hela with the transport ship close behind him and he turns away from Hela to run toward the grandmaster ship. So it must be at the bifrost end. So the argument would be whether there is enough time from when Loki got in the ship to get everyone to the bifrost and you are probably right they wouldn't have made it.

Comment: Yep — I stand corrected, you guys are totally right. Thor certainly lands on the bridge on the Asgard side, and fights his way through the last of the undead army there. When he reaches Loki's ship, Valkyrie joins him from the other (i.e. Bifrost observatory) side, where she's been fighting through the other lot of undead soldiers that started behind Fenris. We need a corrected version of that 8-bit sequence!